# How to use ethers js event filters to filter newest events only?

Tags: ethers.js, events, react

For context, I'm trying to display the balance of a staking pool on my UI. Specifically, I want the balance to be updated every time there is a successful deposit made. I'm not sure how I actually go about creating the filter for the ethers js event filter.

This is what my smart contract event looks like:

```
  event DepositMade(address indexed capitalProvider, uint256 amount, uint256 indexed blockNumber);
```

This is what my react js looks like:

```
const checkEvents = async() => {
  const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)
  const startBlockNumber = await provider.getBlockNumber();
  let juniorPool = new ethers.Contract(juniorPoolAddress, JuniorPool.abi, provider)


  juniorPool.on("DepositMade",  (capitalProvider, amount, blockNumber)=>{

    console.log(usdcBalance);
    console.log(parseInt(amount));
    setusdcBalance(parseInt(`${usdcBalance}`) + parseInt(amount));
  })
}
```

I've been told that I use `contract.filters.EVENT_NAME( ...args ) ⇒ Filter` to filter through events, but I'm still confused on how to manipulate the actual filter to exhibit the behavior I want.

Answer (score 0):

you should use a [web socket provider](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/other/#WebSocketProvider)

here you can see how to use [Alchemy](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/api-providers/#AlchemyProvider)

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.AlchemyProvider.getWebSocketProvider(
"goerli",
 alchemyApiKey
 );
```

another option:

```
new ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider( [ url [ , network ] ] )
```

example:

```
var const provider = new ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider("wss://goerli.infura.io/ws/v3/idhere", "goerli");
```

and then you can use your provider:

```
const contract = new ethers.Contract(juniorPoolAddress, JuniorPool.abi, provider);

contract.on("DepositMade", (capitalProvider, amount, blockNumber) => {
   //your code here
});
```